# Есть два запроса как их объединить

Tags: javascript

Первый обработчик при вводе инфы в инпут выбирает её а второй выбирает инфу из селекта,вопрос как объединить их в один?

```
function showHint(str) {
if (str.length==0) { 
document.getElementById("support").innerHTML="";
return;
}
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState!=4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","22.php",true);
var searchString = "id=" + str; //+ encodeURIComponent(times);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xmlhttp.send(searchString);

  }
```

второй обработчик

```
 function change(st) {
 if (st.length==0) {// otdel
document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML="";
return;
 }
 var xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
}
 }
  xmlhttp1.open("POST","22.php",true);
 var searchString1 = "doc=" +st; //+ encodeURIComponent(times);
        xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",  searchString.length);
        // Отправка данных
        xmlhttp1.send(searchString1);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Если имелось введу выполнение одного запроса вместо двух, то без поддержки сервером ни как!   Если сервер поддерживает пакетные запросы, то обычно так:

```
params=[{id:<id>},{doc:<doc>}]
```

Другими словами сервер должен поддерживать параметр принимающий массив объектов, каждый из которых должен содержать параметры своего запроса. А будет ли это GET или POST в общем случае значения не имеет.

Если имелось введу объединение двух функций в одну, то это возможно конечно. Просто вынесите общую часть (отправку запроса и проверку на приём ответа или возникновение ошибки) в отдельную функцию, а оставшийся код оптимизируйте под это. Это будет правильно и с любой точки зрения. Так же можно воспользоваться jQuery.